# Force comment form to show

Tags: 6, media

I was trying to make my comments form show on a node type that has gallery assist but for some reason it doesnt have any options to change the value to make it show.

is there a module or some sort of way using hook form alter to force the default comments form to show on a node type?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go into the Edit Content type form simply turn on comments.  Are you sure the option is not there?

Comment: It has the options but when it is turned on it doesn't show for the generated nodes